# Error in converting integer to spreadsheet column_id (1 to 'A', 2 to 'B'...)

Tags: c++, string

I want to convert an integer entered into spreadsheet column_id ,that is
1 to A, 2 to B, 26 to Z, 27 to AA and so on.
My code is running correctly for all inputs except for the multiples of 26 and I am unable to form the logic for it. What could be the possible logic for it?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<algorithm> 
 using namespace std;
 int main(){
     int a,n;
     string b;
     cin>>a;
     b="";
     while(a){
         b+=((a%26)+'A'-1);
         a/=26;
     }
     reverse(b.begin(),b.end());
     cout<<b<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Input-

```
26
```

Output-

```
A@
```

Expected Output-

```
Z
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  You'll see that characters don't automatically wrap around, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Question for you: what is the value of `26%26`?

Comment: ...and along the same line, `26/26` ? Hint: it isn't `0`.

Comment: I know where I am doing wrong but I am unable to form the logic for the multiples of 26 ,I am asking help to form the logic

Comment: @Mat ,I know its 0 but I am unable to form the logic for multiples of 26

Comment: and @WhozCraig ,its 1 but I am unable to form the logic for the multiples of 26

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first of all: Why is this error occurring?

If you chose to enter 26 as an value for `a` you are calculating the value for `b` as follows:

```
b += ((26 % 26) + 'A' - 1); // or
```

```
b += (0 + 'A' - 1); // or
```

```
b += 'A' - 1; // which is equal to the '@' symbol
```

So obviously you do not wan't to subtract from the letter it self. But what happens if you decrease `a` before using the modulo operator?

```
a--;
while (a) {
  b+=static_cast<char>('A' + (a % 26)); 
  a/=26;
}
```

Well this will now work correctly for values from 1-26 but will not work for values above 26 an won't enter the loop in case you enter 1 for `a`. Switching to a do-while loop will fix the latter but there will still be an issue. For every number greater than 26 you will get an string wich is 27 cells ahead (so `BA` instead of `AA`). But by moving `a--` into the loop this will be fixed as well:

```
do { 
  a--;
  b+=static_cast<char>('A' + (a % 26)); // static_cast not needed just for clarity
  a/=26;
} while(a);
```

[***Here***](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3k0axYentrMYV4RF) is a working example.